# Making use of the key attribute in React JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, kaios

I have an array of values coming from an API, it contains the list of values. I am mapping all these values in an array of cards (*as mentioned in the code below*). I need to extract the id of the selected element, it is stored in the **key** attribute. Is there a way to use/reference the value of the key attribute?

```js
{data.map((item) => (
          <Card key={item[0]} element={item} />
        ))}
```

I am developing a KaiOS app and hence cursor interactions (onClick or onHover) are restricted. There is a nav-focus attribute (maintained using a custom hook) which is used to determine if the current element is selected and used CSS to highlight it (*as shown in the image below*) on that basis. I don't want to maintain a state of the selected element as it would be updated every time I navigate amongst the cards.

I would like to know if there is a way to use the **key attribute** of the selected item

[image: Image from wikiHow showing a highlighted option]

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to maintain a state of the selected element as it would be updated every time I navigate amongst the cards.

State is the correct way, why the want for not using state.

Keys should be used for uniquely identifying items rendered as a list, e.g. using `map()` and shouldn't really be used as other props would be.

Comment: It was just out of curiosity. To find if there was any other way possible. Maintaining state was my last resort.

Answer (score 1):

Use a key in the html. It will solve the problem you suggested. and it will get the selected item as an attribute by the getAttribute property.

```
<div>
      <select onChange = {this.onSelect}>
       <option key="1" language="english">English</option> 
       <option key="2" language="espanol">Espanol</option> 
            </select> 
</div>
```

Now onSelect function which will console log the selected language:

```
onSelect=(event)=> {
    const selectedIndex = event.target.options.selectedIndex;
    console.log(event.target.options[selectedIndex].getAttribute('language'));
  }
```